# Makefile: Interpolate variable uuid in command

Tags: bash, macos, makefile

I want to write a command so it runs using a randomly generated uuid each time, interpolating this variable into the command.

I'm in MacOS, so I can use the `uuidgen` command

```bash
❯ uuidgen
E4BC7525-1EC7-4338-8F4F-8DA268CB7051
```

I want to interpolate this value as part of my command like that:

```bash
send-test-sqs-message: ## Send test sqs message to generate an email
  aws sqs send-message "{\"identifier\":$(uuidgen), ..." --output table | cat
```

But the output when running `make send-test-sqs-message` shows that "identifier" is empty.

Running the command with `set -x` provides this extra output which doesn't look relevant:

```
+_p9k_preexec1:1> _p9k_restore_special_params +_p9k_restore_special_params:1> (( ! 0 )) +_p9k_restore_special_params:7> (( ! 0 )) +_p9k_restore_special_params:11> (( ! 0 )) +_p9k_preexec1:2> unset __p9k_trapint +_p9k_preexec1:3> trap - INT +omz_termsupport_preexec:1> [[ '' != true ]]
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: I don't see an error in your code. What do you see exactly when you run it with `set -x`?

Comment: What I do not understand in your code: Do you have two commands running, the first is `send-test-sqs-message:` and the second is `aws`? The name of the first command (with the colon at the end) looks a bit unusual.

Comment: send-test-sqs-message is the Make command, and aws sqs send-message is a AWS cli command very long (I just wrote a simplified version for showing purposed) that is run from make.

Comment: Have you tried `$$(uuidgen)`

Comment: Don't write this in a comment - it's virtually unreadable. Edit your question by pasting these lines.

Comment: BTW, I just notice that you have tagged this as _makefile_, but the text of your question does no mention any use of _make_.  You need to clarify, **how** you are running the commands, otherwise we can't tell what's wrong.

Comment: @Philippe yes, but then it treats the variable as plain text and the output command looks like this: `--message-body "{\"identifier\":$(uuidgen),...`